# How to pass data between two components, React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, parent-child, react-native-flatlist

Im a begginer in React Native. Im trying to pass data between two components in my app. I have components - Home.js and MyModal.js.

In the first component - Home.js - I have an array with some data and FlatList component. Home.js displays data in my app correctly.
Additionally, in home.js, I'm trying to display Modal, when user clicks on a Card in TouchableOpacity component:

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => <MyModal />}>
<Card></Card>  </TouchableOpacity>
```

In the second component - MyModal.js- I'm trying to display data /item.title/ and /item.body/ from home.js.

Here is all code:

home.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {StyleSheet,View,Text,FlatList,TouchableOpacity} from "react-native";
import Card from "../components/card";
import MyModal from "../components/myModal"


function Home({ navigation }) {
  const [reviews, setReviews] = useState([
    {
      body: "lorem ipsum",
      key: " 1",
      title: "Flower",
    },
    {
      key: "2",
      title: "Two flowers",
  
      body: "lorem ipsum",
    }
  ]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
     
      <FlatList
        data={reviews}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => <MyModal />}>
            <Card>
              <Text>{item.title}</Text>
              <Text>{item.body}</Text>
            </Card>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

myModal.js

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, Button, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import Card from "../components/card";

export default function MyModal({ route, navigation }) {

  return (
    <View>
      <Card>
        <Text>{data.title}</Text>
        <Text>{data.body}</Text>
      </Card>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Here is exaple what I want to display:

Home.js before click:
[image]

Screen after click (opened MyModal.js with data from home.js):
[image]

Here is the codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-fermat-lui4g

I will be grateful for any advice

Answer (score 1):

Hear is the way where you can pass data other component following Way

First You define NavigationContainer root Page of app like below

```
<NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen options={{ headerShown: false }} name="Home" component= 
        {HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Gallery" component={GalleryScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="GalleryDetails"
            component={GalleryDetailsScreen}
        />
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

Than Class Where Your used Navigation My Code Gallery

```
const gallery = () => {
const navigation = useNavigation();

}

 navigation.navigate('GalleryDetails', { imageURI(Key): 
              item.node.image.uri(Value)});
```

Hear GalleryDetails I fatch    Data as Below

```
    var imageURI = route.params.imageURI;
    console.log(imageURI);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. How can I use it with <MyModal> component in my case? I want to display modal using onPress, as in my code:           <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => <MyModal />}>

Answer (score 0):

```
  <View style={styles.container}>
   
    <FlatList
      data={reviews}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress=props.navigation.push('nameOfRouteModal', 
          itemToPast)>
          <Card>
            <Text>{item.title}</Text>
            <Text>{item.body}</Text>
          </Card>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
    />
  </View>
);
}

export default function MyModal({ route, navigation }) {
const routeParams = route.params;
return (
  <View>
    <Card>
      <Text>{routeParams.title}</Text>
      <Text>{routeParams.body}</Text>
    </Card>
  </View>
);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Dedi, I was trying to implement this solution, but unfortunatelly I have an error "props is not defined". Is this code complete?

Answer (score 0):

jus do it like this:

```
 function Home({ navigation }) {
// take a state by default null when a record is clicked it will be updated. and //pass it to the Modal like below 
const [currentReview , setCurrentView] = useState(null)
  const [reviews, setReviews] = useState([
    {
      body: "lorem ipsum",
      key: " 1",
      title: "Flower",
    },
    {
      key: "2",
      title: "Two flowers",
  
      body: "lorem ipsum",
    }
  ]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
     
      <FlatList
        data={reviews}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {setCuurentReview(item); <MyModal 
          currentReview={currenReview} />}>
            <Card>
              <Text>{item.title}</Text>
              <Text>{item.body}</Text>
            </Card>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

then catch it like this:

```
    export default function MyModal({ route, navigation, currentReview }) {

  return (
    <View>
      <Card>
        <Text>{data.title}</Text>
        <Text>{data.body}</Text>
      </Card>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi @Dawood Ahmad, I was trying to implement this solution, but unfortunatelly nothing happend onPress - my modal doesnt open. Is this code complete?